# How to import and assign user roles from existing database schema to Keycloak

Tags: spring

I already have a db schema with users and roles.
Now am using Spring DaoAuthenticationProvider. I want to migrate to Keycloak Auth.
I am create custom user federation provider, which collect users from db schema and create relative Keycloak users. But, i don't know how to import roles for that users.

Comment: How do you did this: "I am create custom user federation provider, which collect users from db schema and create relative Keycloak users"?